# IntelliJ IP Address VM Options

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The Java app at my work requires you to put your IP address into the vm options as -DHOST=xx.xx.xx.xxx into the run configurations.
My ip address is constantly changing for some reason so I need to keep going into the intellij configuration and updating it with my new IP Address. Is there anyway to have the -DHOST linked to my IPAddress so I don't manually have to type it in?

UPDATE:
as mentioned below using 127.0.0.1 fixed my issue and I haven't had to update it since!

Comment: Your machine's local IP address is always `127.0.0.1` - also known as `localhost` - would that work?  (without knowing more about your app, it's hard to tell if this will be enough to solve the issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use static IP address with like 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thank you for solving my question with the detail provided

Comment: My Pleasure @andresmonc